# While running, crashing program (Codeblock C++)

Tags: c++

I started work with dynamic memory, and while program running it's crashing. My input is 26 payments, and output to .csv file where payments number is 25 cause program crashing nad allocated memory is wrong (Sorry for my bad english, I guess you understand what i meaning).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
      int year, month, day, payments;
      float total, presentValue, interestRate;
      float *Remaining, *Principal, *Interest;
      cout << "Insert date" << endl;
      cin >> year >> month >> day;
      cout << "Insert Present Value" << endl;
      cin >> presentValue;
      cout << "Insert Interest Rate" << endl;
      cin >> interestRate;
      cout << "Insert number of payments" << endl;
      cin >> payments;
      Remaining = new(nothrow)float[payments];
      Principal = new(nothrow)float[payments];
      Interest = new(nothrow)float[payments];
      Remaining[0] = presentValue;
      total = (Remaining[0] * (interestRate / 1200)) / (1 - pow(1 + (interestRate / 1200), payments*(-1)));
      cout << total;
      ofstream myfile;
      myfile.open ("payments3.csv");
      myfile << "Payment #;Payment date;Remaining amount; \
      Principal payment;Interest payment;Total payment;Interest rate" << endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < payments; i++) {
            myfile << i+1 << ";";
            if (month > 12) {
                month = 1;
                year += 1;
            }
            myfile << year << '-'
            << month << '-'
            <<  day
            << ";";
            month++;
            Interest[i] = Remaining[i] * (interestRate / 1200);
            Principal[i] = total - Interest[i];
            Remaining[i+1] = Remaining[i] - Principal[i];
            myfile << fixed << showpoint;
            myfile << setprecision(2);
            myfile << Remaining[i] << ";" << Principal[i] << ";" << Interest[i] << ";\
            " << total << ";" << interestRate << endl;
      }
      myfile.close();
      delete[] Remaining;
      delete[] Principal;
      delete[] Interest;
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the following line tries to access out of range:

```
Remaining[i+1] = Remaining[i] - Principal[i];
```

try this:

```
if (i + 1 < payments)
    Remaining[i+1] = Remaining[i] - Principal[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `Remaining[0]` and `Remaining[i+1]` specially, which probably means that you need one extra element of that array.

Otherwise the `[i+1]` will be out of bounds during the last turn in the loop.